# Combining Knockout if binding with data binding in one line

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, devextreme

Is it somehow possible to combine Knockout's if binding with another binding in the same line? I want to show and execute a binding to a div only, if a condition is true. A chart should only show up, if the user has the right to see it.

My chart definition is pretty simple:

```
<div style="height:150px" data-bind="dxChart: chartSettings"></div>
```

Can I just add the if binding before the dxChart binding? Or is it unavoidable to use the comment if binding in this context, like this?

```
<!-- ko if: hasRights -->
<div style="height:150px" data-bind="dxChart: chartSettings"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: It's pretty much unavoidable short of making your own custom binding that combines the two. You can't have more than one binding on the same element which use controlsDescendantBindings: true

Comment: That's essentially any binding that adds/removes elements from the DOM. the "if" binding is definitely in that category and from the name I'm guessing dxChart does as well. As suggested by Nisarg the "visible" binding might work since it only changes css to hide the element, but if hidden isn't enough you'll have to use the wrapper element or virtual element.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="height:150px" data-bind="dxChart: chartSettings, if: hasRights">
    ... Elements ...
</div>
```

This wouldn't affect the div itself, but only the elements contained in the div.

You could use the `visible` binding - which will hide the entire div (including the children), but as you might know, it doesn't prevent the div from being added to the DOM:

```
<div style="height:150px" data-bind="dxChart: chartSettings, visible: hasRights">
    ... Elements ...
</div>
```

So, yes, wrapping the div in the comment based binding [(containerless control flow syntax)](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) is one of the solutions. Another solution would be to wrap in a div that has the `if` binding. Something like:

```
<div data-bind="if: hasRights">
    <div style="height:150px" data-bind="dxChart: chartSettings">
        ... Elements ...
    </div>
</div>
```